# How do I create JSON from parsed HTML table using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, json, css-selectors, html-parsing, nokogiri

I want to create A JSON object from each `TR` from [this site](http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm).

For now I'm able to get the whole table and each `TR` but it is not enough... That's why I'm confused.

Here is an example of the JSON I want in return. This one is for chapter 07:

```
{
  "chapter":"07",
  "title":"LIFTING AND SHORING",
  "description":"This chapter shall...",
  "section":[
    {
      "number":"00",
      "title":"GENERAL",
      "description":"",
    },

    {
      "number":"10",
      "title":"JACKING",
      "description":"Provides information relative...",
    },

    {
      "number":"20",
      "title":"SHORING",
      "description":"Those instructions necessary...",
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is to get this whole thing at once, but here is what I've managed so far:

```
parsed_html.css("table")[1].css("tr")
```

I'm using Nokogiri for parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really not a problem to choose for learning Ruby. The data is awkward and unreliable, and it would be a useful programming challenge for a language you knew relatively well. When you are learning a language you need tasks that are relatively simple but will test your knowledge of the language itself.

I have written this, which complies at least with your example for chapter `07`.

It works by choosing a (the only) table from the page that has more than one row. Then it iterates through those rows, extracting an array of fields, converting non-breakable spaces to ordinary spaces and stripping leading and trailing spaces. All empty fields are discarded, and the whole row is ignored if it contains no data.

Then a row where the first column starts with decimal digits indicates the first line of a chapter, or if there is a preceding hyphen then it is section information for the same chapter.

If a field was absent from the source (the *description* fields and the *section titles*) I would normally choose to omit it from the intermediate data. However I have defaulted these fields to an empty string to comply with your example of expected JSON output. (There is a difference between a non-existent hash element and one that has a value of `nil`.)

I hope this helps.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'

open('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm') do |f|

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
  table = doc.at_xpath('//table[count(tr) > 1]')

  chapters = []
  chapter = nil

  table.xpath('tr').each do |tr|

    td = tr.xpath('td')
    td = td.map { |td| td.content.gsub("\u00A0", ' ').strip }
    td = td.select { |txt| not txt.empty? }
    next if td.empty?

    if td[0] =~ /^\d+/

      chapters << chapter if chapter

      chapter = {
          'chapter'     => td[0],
          'title'       => td[1],
          'description' => td[2] || ''
      }

    elsif td[0] =~ /^-(\d+)/

      section = {
          'number'      => $1,
          'title'       => td[1] || '',
          'description' => td[2] || ''
      }

      chapter['section'] ||= []
      chapter['section'] << section
    end

  end

  chapters << chapter if chapter

  puts JSON.pretty_generate(chapters)

end
```

**(partial) output**

```
{
  "chapter": "07",
  "title": "LIFTING AND SHORING",
  "description": "This chapter shall include the necessary procedures to lift and shore aircraft in any of the conditions to which it may be subjected.  Includes lifting and shoring procedures that may be employed during aircraft maintenance and repair.",
  "section": [
    {
      "number": "00",
      "title": "GENERAL",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "number": "10",
      "title": "JACKING",
      "description": "Provides information relative to jack points, adapters, tail supports, balance weights, jacks and jacking procedures utilized during aircraft maintenance and repair."
    },
    {
      "number": "20",
      "title": "SHORING",
      "description": "Those instructions necessary to support the aircraft during maintenance and repair.  Includes information on shoring materials and equipment, contour dimensions, shoring locations, etc."
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: What you have done here... I'm stunned! Now I know why this task was such a big deal for me. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for and clarifies everything. I owe you a pint of good beer :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very difficult in general because the markup has been done manually and very badly, and there is *no* reliable way of extracting the data across updates.

For instance

- There are *two* Chapter 01s: *INTRODUCTION* and *OPERATIONS INFORMATION*
- The chapter number is sometimes just numeric, like `05`, and sometimes a mixture, like `72(R)`
- Chapters up to 23 have the title in the second column with a `colspan="2"` attribute on the `td` element, but chapters after that have a blank second column and the title in the third column
- There is erratic and spurious use of non-breakable space `U+00A0`, which the `String` class doesn't recognize as whitespace
- There are blank lines with a grey background that have `bgcolor="#CCCCCC"` that could be used to separate the chapter information. But again we are relying on the accuracy of manual input
- Is anything to be done with the *GROUP DEFINITION* lines in the table?

This would be reasonably straightforward if the program doesn't have to extract data from other similar pages, or from a (manually) modified version of the same page. Otherwise you have to bow to the fact that manually-entered data can't be parsed and give up.

Comment: No, there is nothing to be done with GROUP DEFINITION and I think the best solution is to separate chapters using this greyed lines (but don't know how...). I only need to extract data from this specifc page and it is one-timer as I want to practice Ruby and avoid some manual work. I need this JSONs for iOS app.